# Syntax error in SQL Server on altering table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER TABLE [BlaBla] 
  ADD TimeStamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
      DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
      ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I am getting below errors

- Incorrect Syntax near ON
- Incorrect Syntax near CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: if your table do not have any record ALTER TABLE [BlaBla] ADD TimeStamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP..

Comment: First of all, the `TIMESTAMP` datatype in SQL Server ***has absolutely nothing*** to do with a date&time - therefore, you **cannot** define a default of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. If you want to record the current date&time, you need to use either `DATE` (if you're interested in the date only, no time), or `DATETIME2(n)` for date & time. And you **cannot** define that `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clause, either  - you'd have to write a **trigger** to update the value upon an update

Comment: Have you read the docs at all? Where did you come up with that statement? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry guys, It was my inexperience with SQL Server that i asked this question. Sorry. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If table have record you can not a not null column to it (directly).

you need step 1

```
  ALTER TABLE [BlaBla] ADD TimeStamp datetime NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

step 2

```
update [BlaBla] set [TimeStamp] =CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where [TimeStamp] is null
```

step 3 no add not null

```
   ALTER TABLE [BlaBla] ADD TimeStamp datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Its not working bro!

Comment: I am trying to execute it on MS-SQL Server.. if that makes a difference!

Comment: what is not working

Comment: Don't worry about it... I just started working on SQL Server and saw this statement somewhere on Stackoverflow , it turns out ON Update is not supported in SQL Server, moreover it just doesn't make sense to use timestamp in the context i was trying it to use. Anyways , Thanks for your time